# Not able to load data from JSON in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, model-view-controller, angular-ui-router

I'm working on loading data from JSON file in Angular 2.

This is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
      "processName": "SOUAD_1",
      "processStatus": "Hibernating",
      "UnprocessedCMSG": 123,
      "TempackedCMSG": 10,
      "DeferredCMSG": 32.99
    },
    {
      "processName": "SOUAD_2",
      "processStatus": "Hibernating",
      "UnprocessedCMSG": 123,
      "TempackedCMSG": 10,
      "DeferredCMSG": 32.99
    },
    {
      "processName": "SOUAD_3",
      "processStatus": "Hibernating",
      "UnprocessedCMSG": 123,
      "TempackedCMSG": 10,
      "DeferredCMSG": 32.99
    }
]
```

This is my ts file where I specified the JSON path...

```
    import {  
    Injectable  
    } from '@angular/core';  

    import {  
    Http,  
    Headers,  
    RequestOptions,  
    Response  
    } from '@angular/http'; 

   import {  
    Observable,  
    Subject  
   } from 'rxjs/Rx';  

   import 'rxjs/Rx'; //get everything from Rx    
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';  
   import {  
    IProduct  
   } from "../models/iproduct"; 

   @Injectable()  
    export class ProcessJsonService {  
    private jsonFileURL: string = "../Data/jsonfile.json";  
    constructor(private http: Http) {}  
    //    
    getProcesslist(): Observable < IProduct[] > {  
    return this.http.get(this.jsonFileURL)
    .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]>response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);    
    }  

    private handleError(errorResponse: Response) {  
        console.log(errorResponse.statusText);  
        return Observable.throw(errorResponse.json().error || "Server error");  
    }  
}
```

this is my my process-list-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from "../models/iproduct";
import {  
  Http  
} from '@angular/http';   
import {  
  ProcessJsonService  
} from '../models/myjsonprocess';  
import {  
  Observable  
} from 'rxjs/Rx'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  pageTitle: string = 'Product List';
  imageWidth: number = 50;
  imageMargin: number = 2;
  showImage: boolean = false;
  listFilter: string = '';
  processList: IProduct[];  
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private _processJsonService: ProcessJsonService) {  
    this.processList = []; 
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {  
        let self = this;  
        self._processJsonService.getProcesslist().subscribe(response => this.processList = response, error => this.errorMessage = < any > error);  
    }  
}
```

this is my process-list-component

```html
    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        {{pageTitle}}
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-2'>Filter by:</div>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='listFilter' />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <h3>Filtered by: {{listFilter}} </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='table'
                   *ngIf='processList && processList.length'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Process Name</th>
                        <th>Process Status</th>
                        <th>Unprocessed CMSG</th>
                        <th>Tempacked CMSG</th>
                        <th>Deferred CMSG</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let process of processList">
                        <td>{{ process.processName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ process.processStatus | lowercase }}</td>
                        <td>{{ process.UnprocessedCMSG }}</td>
                        <td>{{ process.TempackedCMSG}}</td>
                        <td>{{ process.DeferredCMSG}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I should get a table where the details of each process are shown. But, in the browser, I'm getting empty page, no data are shown.
Please, any help ??

This is what I'm getting in the console:

```
AppComponent.html:7 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ProductListComponent -> ProcessJsonService]:
```

StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ProductListComponent -> ProcessJsonService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ProcessJsonService!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:994)

Comment: I bet your `jsonFileURL` is not a valid URL...

Comment: it's the path of my json file it's under app in data folder.

I tried with one of the json test URLs from web and with no success too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
.subscribe(response => this.processList = response
```

And then in your template:

```
*ngFor="let process of processList | async"
```

You only use `async` pipe to retrieve values from an `Observable/Promise`. `processList` is neither of them, you already subscribed to the data and stored it in the variable, so just remove the `async` pipe from the template.

Comment: I removed the async pipe and still not getting data displayed in the browser.
I updated the question by removing the async pipe